# Mysql slow multiple join query - version 5.7

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
        FROM `ResearchEntity` AS `ResearchEntity`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `UserEntity` AS `createdBy` ON `ResearchEntity`.`createdById` = `createdBy`.`id`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item1Entity` AS `item1` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item1`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item2Entity` AS `item2` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item2`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item3Entity` AS `item3` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item3`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item4Entity` AS `item4` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item4`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item5Entity` AS `item5` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item5`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item6Entity` AS `item6` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item6`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item7Entity` AS `item7` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item7`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item8Entity` AS `item8` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item8`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item9Entity` AS `item9` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item9`.`researchId`
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Item10Entity` AS `item10` ON `ResearchEntity`.`id` = `Item10`.`researchId`
ORDER BY `ResearchEntity`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 20, 40;
```

`UserEntity` has 4 records
`Item*Entity` each has 15 records

When I remove the first join, the `UserEntity` join the query runs very fast, but with it is runs in 50 seconds.

The query is built dynamically in runtime using a ORM.

Why `UserEntity` is causing this much trouble?

Thanks

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT (your query); B) SHOW CREATE TABLE ResearchEntity; and C) SHOW CREATE TABLE createdBy; for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

- Try changing your select * to select specific fields from each entity, the load of your query will be reduced and run time should be faster. something like:

```
SELECT ResearchEntity.field1 as ReField1, item1.name as Item1Name, ...
```

-- Edit

- Also, try to keep the smaller tables to the left of the JOIN statements.
- Ensure you index the joining fields and the joining fields are INT
- If you are sure that one Table is causing too much time, consider fetching results of that table separately in your code